# How to call a server side function from client in meteor

Tags: meteor

This is the function I want to call.

server/function

```
Meteor.methods({
  ok:function () {
    for (var i =0;i<10;i++) {
      console.log("ok");
    } 
  }
});
```

### Edit

Using `Meteor.call('ok')` did not work.

The function should print ok to the server console 10 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try;

```
Meteor.call('ok');
```

Comment: yes I did try Meteor.call(); I don't know why it does not work.

Comment: Yes but did you try Meteor.call('ok'), with 'ok' inside because it's the name of your method, otherwise just doing Meteor.call() will not work.

Comment: `Meteor.call('ok', function (err, result) { ... })`

Comment: Where are you looking for console.log ? In the browser? If you're methods are in the server folder then you will need to look at your terminal. That's were the console.log is being outputted.

Comment: And console.log - server console (-:

Comment: @Perspective I know it is not printing ok to the terminal.

Comment: @imslavko how would that look

Comment: @noah I added your code to /server/methods.js, in the client I just added Meteor.call('ok') and in the terminal got ok 10 times.

Comment: @Perspective I just tried it in the browser console andit worked but in header js i'll try and see whats i did wrong thanks